# Fragment hosting another fragment, how to reference host fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a fragment which contains a ViewPager. This ViewPager is obviously populated by other Fragments.

My question is, is there any way (something resembling getActivity()) for the Fragment in the ViewPager to get a reference to the host Fragment?

Comment: why do you want a reference to the host fragment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as it is API 17 or greater, you can use this:

```
getParentFragment()
```

It will return null if the fragment is inside of an activity, not another fragment.

See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment%28%29).

Comment: Precisely what I needed. Thank you sir!